# How to position text label in the x axis using zedgraph API?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am in the middle of my project using the Zedgraph API and I got stack on how to position the TextObj at the Bottom of the graph as label. Could any one help me? any hint is a big help. Thank you!

Code :

`TextObj tb = new TextObj(new XDate(x).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"), x,_zedcontrol.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Min);

_zedcontrol.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Add(tb);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextObj` constructor comes in several overloads. In some of these overloads, you can specify the `CoordType`. In your case, I assume the best choice is `CoordType.ChartFraction`. The coordinates should then be given as fractions of the chart area, with origin at top-left. Coordinates may be negative or large than one. Alignment can also be controlled via the `AlighH` and `AlignV` arguments.

Here is an example where the text object is placed approximately aligned with the X axis labels (and where the text object is drawn behind the axis):

```
var text = new TextObj("On X Axis", 0.02, 1.03, CoordType.ChartFraction, 
                       AlignH.Left, AlignV.Top);
text.ZOrder = ZOrder.D_BehindAxis;
_zedcontrol.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Add(text);
```

This will result in the following graph:

[image: Text object on X axis]

Comment: thank you very much for the reply Anders! however, I need the label at the very bottom of the graph which means that it will be displayed along with the numbers in the x-axis. So, in your illustration, I would need for the label "Bottom Left" to be aligned with the labels of the x-axis. I hope you could help me on this. :)
God bless!

Comment: @Cold I have updated my answer. Hope it is more in line with what you are after.

Comment: @Andres, If you don't mind I have a question about the zedgraph. Is it possible that the axis scale outside the graph could be scale using the mouse event "mouse_down  and hold" and move up or down in y-axis the same with the x-axis move left or right? ex. when I MouseDownEvent and hold the x-axis scale 0.6 or at the space along with that scale and move it to the right, scale should move depend in the chartfraction? could you post an example? Thank you!

Comment: @Cold Glad to hear it worked. Please do not forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23138). Considering your mouse-axis-drag concern, I recommend that you post this as a separate question here on Stackoverflow. This way you will have better chances of getting a good answer to that question as well.

Comment: @Andres, I am new with this forum and didn't know that I need to accept or how to do it. But now I knew it already. Thanks! :)